# How do I access array of hash in perl and compare values to the desired string?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

Actually i have an array of hash in Perl and i have to iterate every hash value and compared to the desired string for eg:

```
@AoH = (
{
   husband  => "barney",
   wife     => "betty",
   son      => "bamm bamm",
},
{
   husband => "george",
   wife    => "jane",
   son     => "elroy",
},

{
   husband => "homer",
   wife    => "marge",
   son     => "bart",
},
);
```

now i have to compare the son value in every iteration.....
what is the best way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply iterate through the array and compare the `son` every time to your desired string.

```
my $new_string;
foreach my $entry (@AoH){
  if($entry->{son} eq $desired_string){
    print "Found it.";
    #assigning the value of 'son' to the $new_string
    $new_string = $entry->{son};
  }
}
```

In this little example the `$desired_string` is the string you compare the `son` value against.

If you're only interested in accessing all the values in all hashes and then search for the pattern you can store the values in a temporary array:

```
my @tempArray;
foreach my $entry (@AoH){
   push @tempArray, values %{$entry};
}

if( grep($_ eq $desired_string) @tempArray){
  print "one hash contains the desired string as an value";
}
```

I wasn't really sure what you want to achieve, but I hope that I could help a bit further.

Comment: `foreach my $entry (@AoH){
  if($entry->{son} eq 'bart'){
    #here i have to store the wife into another variable
my $new_string=wife;
  }
}`

the above approach is right or Not Sir???

Comment: Youre basically right, but please check your syntax: `foreach my $entry (@AoH){ if ( ...) { my $new_string = $entry->{wife} }}` consider to declare the `$new_string` outside the `foreach` loop if you want to work with it later in another scope.

Comment: @Otterbein: Please don't solicit up-votes or acceptances

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you mean by compare. If you're looking to do many types of comparisons *between* hashes where son is the primary focus, I'd suggest creating a hash who's keys are the son's name, and value is an array of `$AoH` indexes.

```
my %sons;
for (my $i = 0; $i < @AoH; $i++) {
    push( @{ $sons{ $AoH[$i]{"son"} } }, $i);
}
```

For the data given, `%sons` will be

```
{
    'elroy' => [1],
    'bamm bamm' => [0],
    'bar' => [2],
}
```

Now you know every family who has a son of that name and can do various things with the data in each shared family.

```
for my $son (keys %sons) {
    my $num_couples = @{$sons{$son}};
    print "There are $num_couples couple(s) with a son who's name is $son.\n";
    for my $i (@{$sons{$son}}) {
        print "Husband: $AoH[$i]{husband}, Wife: $AoH[$i]{wife}\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Or if you want to know if any family has a son named "George", you can search `%son`'s keys.

```
my $test_name = "George";
for my $son (keys %sons) {
    if ($son eq $test_name) {
        print "At least one family has a son named $test_name.\n";
        last;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you really want to do but basically if you want the hash back if son name eq 'myson' then do with one liner:

```
my @hash_with_myson = grep {$_->{son} eq 'myson'} @AoH;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write a "for" loop on i and access "son" by :

```
$AoH[i]{son}
```

Comment: for my $i (@AoH){
 if($AoH[i]{son} == 'bart')
print "Son is there";
 } 
My approach is right??

Comment: In Perl you have to compare string with the `eq` comparator rather than with `==` which is only for numbers. With the correct syntax of your counted loop `for(my $i = 0; $i < @AoH; $i++)` your approach is right.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $son='xxx';
my $result;
foreach my $family(@AoH) {
    push(@$result,$family) if($family->{son} eq $son);
}

foreach my $family(@$result) {
    print $family->{husband}.' '.$family->{wife}.' '.$family->{son} . "\n";
}
```